# AndroidSlidingUpPanelLayout shows List elements only after recollapsing

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am currently trying to implement the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) using a ListView as the main layout and a Relative Layout as the sliding layout. This is the XML I am using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.sothree.slidinguppanel"
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bar_background"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        sothree:collapsedHeight="40dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/song_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="42"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/bar_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that the content of the list only becomes visible after expanding and collapsing the sliding layout once. The SlidingUpPanelLayout itself is embedded into a Fragment which lies inside a FragmentPagerAdapter. I also notice that the content of the list disappears after sliding two fragments away from it (and back again).
Here is the code of the Fragment:

```
public abstract class Songs extends Fragment {
    protected ArrayList<String> elements;
    protected SonglistAdapter adapter;

    public Songs(ArrayList<String> es) {
        elements = es;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_songlist, container, false);

        ListView lview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        adapter = new SonglistAdapter(inflater, elements);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and here its Adapter:

```
public class SonglistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> elements;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SonglistAdapter(LayoutInflater infl, ArrayList<String> es) {
        elements = es;
        inflater = infl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return elements.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout layer = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_songlist_item, parent, false);

        // fill current item with information
        TextView view = (TextView) layer.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        view.setText(elements.get(position));

        return layer;
    }
}
```

I am creating the Fragment in the FragmentPagerAdapter as follows:

```
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add("Hello");
    arr.add("Bye");

    ContentHandler.overviewFragment = new Overview(arr);
```

'ContentHandler.overviewFragment' is then returned in 'public Fragment getItem(int index)' (in the usual way).

I tried looking through the source of AndroidSlidingUpPanel and thought that the error might be in [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java) file in the 'protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)' function, but I could not find any difference between the calls on startup and the calls on recollapse of the sliding panel.
So my question would be if any of you knows what is wrong with my implementation.

PS: As this is my first submission, I'd be happy to improve my post in any possible way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by setting the `layout_height` of the ListView to `match_parent`